# Express the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

> Let p>1. Express the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}}$ in terms of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^p}}$.

Since we have p>1, we know that all of them converge, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}}$ converges absolutely.

For the first one, I am considering a relationship like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)^p}}$=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}}$+$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2\cdot n^p}}$. I don't know whether I am on the right track.
For the second one, are they equal? I have no idea on that. I hope someone can give me some hints on this problem.

Comment: With the second one, split even and odd terms as well to get rid of the numerator

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the first. It is
$$1+\frac1{3^p}+\frac1{5^p}+\frac1{7^p}+\cdots.$$
This is
$$1+\frac1{2^p}+\frac1{3^p}+\frac1{4^p}+\cdots\tag{1}$$
minus
$$\frac1{2^p}+\frac1{4^p}+\frac1{6^p}+\cdots\tag{2}.$$
Can you relate $(2)$ to $(1)$?